# Scrolling my listview re-run my code for all my items

Tags: java, xamarin

I'm using a custom adapter with clickable items inside.The problem is that when i'm scrolling listview it re-runs my codes which exist in item click.
How can i disable listview doing this?

Here is an example of my adapter:

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null)
        {
            row = LayoutInflater.From(mContext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.InventoryPreview, null, false);

        }

        TextView txtInventoryName = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtInventoryName);

         Button ExtraBtn = row.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.ExtrasBtn);




        txtInventoryName.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var db = new SQLiteConnection(Connection.dpPath);
            db.CreateTable<OrderPreviewClass>();
            OrderPreviewClass tbl = new OrderPreviewClass();

            Connection.InventoryItemID = mitems[position].InventoryItemID;
            Connection.InventoryItemName = mitems[position].InventoryItemName;
            Connection.RetailPrice = mitems[position].InventoryItemPrice;
            Connection.Quantity = "1";

            tbl.CategoryID = Connection.CategoryID;
            tbl.InventoryItemID = Connection.InventoryItemID;
            tbl.Description = Connection.InventoryItemName;
            tbl.Quantity = Connection.Quantity;
            tbl.Price = Connection.RetailPrice;
            tbl.ExtrasPrice = "0";
            tbl.RealPrice = Connection.RetailPrice;
            tbl.Extras = ",";
            db.Insert(tbl);
            Toast toast = Toast.MakeText(mContext, "x1 " + txtInventoryName.Text, ToastLength.Short);
            toast.Show();

        };
        ExtraBtn.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {

            Connection.InventoryItemID = mitems[position].InventoryItemID;
            Connection.InventoryItemName = mitems[position].InventoryItemName;
            Connection.RetailPrice = mitems[position].InventoryItemPrice;
            Toast toast = Toast.MakeText(mContext, txtInventoryName.Text, ToastLength.Short);
            toast.Show();
            mContext.StartActivity(typeof(ExtrasPreviewMain));


        };



        return row;
    }
```

How can i stop to re-run my code every time listview is scrolling? Should i use ClickListener?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that your cells get recycled, so every time the cell is recycled you are adding another event to the text control and button - events in C# are multicast delegates, so can fire multiple things.

Every time a cell is recycled another event handler is added.

The easies fix would be to extract both handlers into methods or local functions instead of lambdas, and always remove the handler before adding.

Something like:

```
void TextHandler(object sender, EventArgs args) =
{
   var db = new SQLiteConnection(Connection.dpPath);
   ... // rest of the handler here
}

// remove the handler - doesn't matter if it's not already set
txtInventoryName.Click -= TextHandler;

// set the handler
txtInventoryName.Click += TextHandler;
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly it doesnt work it seems to get the same problem.